# GCC compiler warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers

I have a pointer called `tempA` that points to a struct:

```
struct SLNode *tempA;
```

I have a function called `sl_find Node()` I call it like this:

```
tempA = sl_findNode(&list, word);
```

where the function `sl_findNode()` looks like:

```
 struct SLNode* sl_findNode (struct SLNode **list, char *str1) {
      assert (list);
      struct SLNode *curr = *list;
      while (curr) {
        if (strcmp(curr->word, str1) == 0) {
          return curr;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
      }
      return NULL;
    }
```

Lastly, `list` is declared as such:

```
struct SLNode *list = NULL;
```

The compiler gives me the warning on line 77:

> tempA = sl_findNode(&list, word);

Does anyone know why?

Word is a char array:

```
char word[30];
```

I read in characters from a text file and add them into word in a loop

Comment: what is your definition of `word`? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122231/warning-assignment-makes-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast) is a possible cause.

Comment: I've updated with what word is

Comment: Compile your program with `-Wstrict-prototypes` - you aren't using a prototype (or a declaration) for `sl_findNode()` in whatever .c file the call is being made from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the function declaration is correct (and in your case, it looks correct), this kind of warning happens when the definition is after the first use of the function, and there is no prototype.

Solving this problem requires either moving the function to be textually before its fist use, or better yet add a prototype of your function above its first use, like this:

```
struct SLNode* sl_findNode (struct SLNode **list, char *str1);
```