# Don't understand reversing the string from a file into another file

Tags: c

```
void stringReverse(char *s) {

char temp;

int i = 0;

int j = strlen(s) - 1;

while (i >= j)
{
    temp = s[i];
    s[i] = s[j]; //swap the characters
    s[j] = temp;
    i++;
    j--;

}

}
```

this is the function `stringReverse(char *s)` in which i have to call to the main function down below

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *in; /* file handle for input */
    FILE *out; /* file handle for output */
    char word[256]; /* char array to store words from input file */

    /* read words from input file, print on separate lines to output file*/
    while ( fscanf(in, " %s", word) != EOF )
    {
        out = stringReverse(char *word);
        fprintf(out, "%s\n", word);
    }

    /* close input and output files */
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I'm having a hard time understanding how I'm supposed to call the `stringReverse` function. My plan is reverse a word from a text file and put its reverse inside another empty file

Comment: Is `s` a parameter or is it a local variable in the function?

Comment: @Dani counter variables... pretty familiar ones in loops.

Comment: Your code looks like it reverses each word , not reverse the file

Comment: When calling functions you do not specify the type. You just specify the parameter. Thus, you call stringReverse as follows: "stringReverse(word)." You are calling it as "stringReverse(char *word)." The types are required for declaring and defining the function, not calling the function.

Comment: _I'm having a hard time understanding how I'm supposed to call the stringReverse function._ As far as I can see, you have already called the `stringReverse` function. Also, please post the whole contents of the `stringReverse` function. And tell us clearly what your problem is. As far as I can see your code does what you intend.

Comment: @Krumia the above is pretty much the whole reverse function excluding declarations.
i get this error:
assigning to 'FILE *' (aka '__sFILE *') from incompatible type 'void'
        out = stringReverse(word)

Comment: `while (i >= j) ` is never satisfied!! try `<=`

Comment: outregarding this line: fprintf(out, "%s\n", word);  the 'out' is expected to be a filepointer, however, it is what?  that is not defined in the code given.  and it is unlikely that the return value from stringReverse() is a filepointer.

Comment: the code that begins with: while (i >= j) will fail as on a word that is an even length, it will end up reversing the center two characters twice.  it should be: while (i > j)

Comment: i reedited because i still dont really understand what's wrong

Comment: you never open a file from which you could read

Answer (score 0):

Ok well. I read all the comments and i don't have enough reputation to comment. So i add an answer.

Your label says **Don't Understand reversing the string**.  There are two ways in reversing the string.

**First way:**

*Input: Hi how are you*
*Output: you are how Hi*

**Second Way**

*Input: Hi how are you*
*Output: uoy era woh iH*

Your final statement says that you want to reverse a file .

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   long loc;
   FILE *in, *out;
   char ch;

   if(argc != 3) {
       printf("Usage: revcopy <source> <destination>.\n");
       exit(1);
   }

   if((in = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL) {
      printf("Cannot open input file.\n");
      exit(1);
   }

  if((out = fopen(argv[2], "wb"))==NULL) {
     printf("Cannot open output file.\n");
     exit(1);
   }

  /* find end of source file */
  fseek(in, 0L, SEEK_END);
  loc = ftell(in);

 /* copy file in reverse order */
 loc = loc-1; /* back up past end-of-file mark */

 while(loc >= 0L) {
    fseek(in, loc, SEEK_SET);
    ch = fgetc(in);
    fputc(ch, out);
    loc--;
}
  fclose(in);
  fclose(out);

  return 0;
}
```

The above code will give you first type of answer ["you are how hi"]..
If you want to reverse it further , you have to use your **stringReverseFunction**.

[I assumed **s** is a word and it's an actual parameter, **i** points to beginning of the word , **j** points to the end of the word. Then it ll work fine]

Answer (score 0):

you can use      `fgets` to store the entire file in string and then perform reverse logic on that.

Link to --> [fgets](http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/File/Getastringfromastreamhowtousefgets.htm)

strrev from the [this Link](http://www8.cs.umu.se/~isak/snippets/strrev.c)

something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>


char *strrev(char *str)
{
/* u can define your own logic here*/
  char *p1, *p2;

  if (! str || ! *str)
        return str;
  for (p1 = str, p2 = str + strlen(str) - 1; p2 > p1; ++p1, --p2)
  {
        *p1 ^= *p2;
        *p2 ^= *p1;
        *p1 ^= *p2;
  }
  return str;
}

int main()
{
   FILE *myFile;
   char myTmpString [100];
char myInvertedString [110];
   myFile = fopen ("input.txt" , "r");
   if (myFile == NULL) 
       perror ("An Error Occured");
   else {
     fgets (myTmpString , 100 , myFile);
    *myInvertedString =  strrev (myTmpString);

     puts (myTmpString);
     fclose (myFile);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*myInvertedString =  strrev (myTmpString);` will lead to `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]`

Comment: yes.. this is deprecreated in c, we can rewrite to avoid this warning --> [link to SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122231/warning-assignment-makes-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast)

Comment: that means, that you are writing the return value of `strrev`, which is a `char*` to the first value of `myInvertedString`, which is a `char`

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you haven't [opened](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm) the files you are intending to read from and write to:

   ```
   in = fopen("path_to_input_file", "r");
   out = fopen("path_to_output_file", "w");
   ```
2. Then, your `stringReverse` function's return type appears to be `void`. Why are you assigning it's return to `out`? That is wrong.
3. Your `stringReverse` function will reverse a string *in place*. So once the function is called upon `word`, the contents of the variable is reversed.

Rest appears to be OK.